# Best way to store a single instance of RLMObject

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm currently developing an iOS app with Realm as the backend data storage. I have a class that is an RLMObject for the user profile. It stores their name, profile picture, stats, etc.

There should only always be one of these objects, however I know implementing a singleton pattern is usually a bad idea. Currently I have it implemented as

```
//AppDelegate.swift, applicationDidFinishLaunching
//If there's no user profiles yet (first time launch), create one

if UserProfile.allObjects().count == 0 {
    let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
    try! realm.transactionWithBlock() {
        realm.addObject(UserProfile())
    }
}


//ProfileViewController.swift
//Get the first UserProfile
var userProfile: UserProfile? {
        get { 
            return UserProfile.allObjects().objectAtIndex(0) as? UserProfile 
        }
}
```

Is there a better way to keep track of a single instance of this class?

Comment: I don't recommend this approach, because every time you get the object you are basically getting it from realm which takes at least about 50 ms to load, regardless of the size of realm, a better solution would be to have multiple instances of your object but keep track of any change through events (take a look at reactive swift)

Comment: I don't want to take this approach, but it does the job for now. Not really interested in adding an entire framework for something so small. Would KVO be an option?

Comment: if it's a simple profile you are storing, then it would make much more sense to you NSUserDefaults class

Comment: I agree with Mohsen with the `NSUserDefaults` pattern. I think you should use it based on the description you're giving us. Anyway, I strongly recommend you to use the Keychain for storing any sensitive information, like an API Token and so on. `NSUserDefaults` may only be used for settings and random info like a profile picture.

Comment: The app will (in the future) be synced on multiple devices, possibly even android as well. That's why I'm more hesitant to follow this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code sample uses a computed property, which will fetch the object from the Realm each time you access it.

Instead, try using a `lazy var` property:

```
lazy var userProfile: UserProfile? = { 
    return UserProfile.allObjects().objectAtIndex(0) as? UserProfile 
}()
```

This type of property will load the object from the Realm only the first time it is accessed. All subsequent accesses will be directly to the object.

Note that, since `UserProfile` is a Realm object, its fields will automatically update in response to changes made to the underlying object in the Realm. Likewise, any changes you wish to make will need to be wrapped within a Realm [write transaction](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#writes).

In terms of your overall architecture, there is nothing wrong with storing a single instance of an object type in a Realm similar to what you are doing. You may want to give your `UserProfile` object a hardcoded constant primary key, then use the 'add or update' version of the update API (see https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#updating-objects). This will allow you to avoid having to explicitly create a new object.

Comment: This sounds like a great solution. Glad to know I wasn't crazy with my thought process. Thanks!